# Find the geometric interpretation of general solution

Tags: geometric-interpretation

Here are the linear equation:
$$2x+z=0$$
$$-x+3y+z=0$$
$$-x+y+z=0$$

I have found that the general solution is,
$$t
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{-1}2\\
        \frac{-1}2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The question asks me to find the geometric interpretation of general solution.
But I have no idea how. I think my limit knowledge of geometric interpretation is not helping me, so some explanation about geometric interpretation would help me a lot.
Thanks you for any help!

Comment: Not sure if your general solution is correct..

Comment: What's that last equation supposed to be? I see -x+y+z but no equal sign.

Comment: Sorry it should be equal to zero, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the parametric equation for a line. Do you see why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Doesn't need to be square for parametric equation?

Comment: @Chow What do you think needs to be square? Try to graph something like $t[1,2]$ in the $(x,y)$ plane to get a feel for what these kinds of graphs look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

$$t
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{-1}2\\
        \frac{-1}2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

represents every multiple of the single vector $[-1/2,-1/2,1]^T$. That one vector represents a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Think of it, and all of its multiples, as a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Positive multiples (positive values of $t$) are on the same side of the origin as the original vector; negative multiples are on the opposite side of the origin. The zero-multiple (taking $t=0$) *is* the origin.

Do you see how this is a description of a line through the origin?